# Updating the last write time for a symbolic link in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, symbolic-link

Is it possible to update the last write time for a symbolic link in Windows?  I can use the following powershell command to update the last write time of a directory, but it doesn't work for a symbolic link:

```
(ls -filter foo).LastWriteTime=Get-Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to set the properties of the symlink will actually the properties of the actual file that it points to. If you look at the file that **foo** points to, you'll see that the LastWriteTime is being updated with the current date.

The only way I know of to update the last write time of the actual symlink is to simply overwrite the symlink with a new one.